# SQL stripping out of characters from free text in SQL results

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8ZmK.png)I am trying to strip the numbers from a columns called NOTE_DESC. If the characters have numbers they should populate the SPECIAL column. If nothing else the JUNK column should have the special characters I am trying to scrub out. However I am getting a variable that shows for SPECIAL the same as the NOTE_DESC and the JUNK column is blank or null.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#DUPE_SUSPECT', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #DUPE_SUSPECT

SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(NOTE_DESC AS varchar)) AS ROW_NUM,
  [NOTE_ID],
  CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar) [NOTE_DESC],
  CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('PEND KEY', CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar)) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar), CHARINDEX('PEND KEY', CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar)), 24)
    WHEN CHARINDEX('"MACESS WORK ITEM(S):', CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar)) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar), CHARINDEX('"MACESS WORK ITEM(S):', CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar)), 38)
    WHEN LEFT(CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar), 2) = 'PK' THEN LEFT(CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar), 18)
    WHEN LEFT(CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar), 1) NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]%' AND
      LEFT(CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar), 1) NOT IN ('...', ',,:', ':', '.', '!', ',', '?') THEN LEFT(CAST([NOTE_DESC] AS varchar), 18)
    ELSE ''
  END [SPECIAL],
  [CREATED_BY_ID],
  [CREATED_TIMESTAMP],
  [CREATED_TEAM_ID],
  [SERV_CCP_INQ_KEY],
  [ACTION_TIMESTAMP] INTO #DUPE_SUSPECT
FROM [dbo].[Staging_CCP_SERVICE_INQ_NOTES]
WHERE CREATED_TIMESTAMP IS NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE #DUPE_SUSPECT
ADD JUNK varchar(max) NULL

SELECT
  *
FROM #DUPE_SUSPECT
ORDER BY ROW_NUM

-- Create the variables used in parsing the string

DECLARE @count int,
        @position int,
        @strText char(5000),
        @row_num int,
        @x int,
        @pend_key char(20),
        @character char(1),
        @junk char(5000);

-- Initialize the variables.  
SET @count = 100
SET @row_num = 1
SET @position = 1;

WHILE @row_num < @count
BEGIN
  SET @strText = (SELECT
    [NOTE_DESC]
  FROM #DUPE_SUSPECT
  WHERE ROW_NUM = @row_num)

  WHILE @position < LEN(@strText)
  BEGIN
    SET @character = SUBSTRING(@strText, @position, 1)
    IF @character IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
    BEGIN
      SET @pend_key = @pend_key + @character
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @junk = @junk + @character

    END
    SET @position = @position + 1
  END
  UPDATE #DUPE_SUSPECT
  SET SPECIAL = @pend_key,
      JUNK = @junk
  WHERE ROW_NUM = @row_num
  SET @row_num = @row_num + 1
  SET @position = 1
  SET @pend_key = ''
END
```

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: The rows all populate except for JUNK which remains null the special row will populate

Answer (score 0):

It's almost impossible to work out what your code is doing without sample data and your table structure, but I can see several (possible) issues with the code in the `WHILE` loop bit.

1. @pend_key and @junk are declared as fixed length chars, so your code to append to them will never work (chars are padded to their full length, so whatever you append will overflow).
2. In any case, they start off with a NULL value so you can't append to that before you initialise them anyway.

So change their declaration and initialise them to empty strings like so:

```
DECLARE @pend_key varchar(20),
        @junk varchar(5000);

SET @pend_key = ''
SET @junk = ''
```

If you're using SQL server 2008 + you can declare and initialise in one, e.g. `DECLARE @pend_key varchar(20) = '';`

3. You're iterating over the @strText variable which could be up to 5000 chars long but appending numbers to @pend_key which is only 20 chars long. This is probably a mistake and at the very least a big waste of time.
4. At the end of the loop you reset the value of @pend_key for the next row, but do not do the same for @junk so it would continue to fill up with characters from previous rows (at least until it gets to 5000 long). I doubt you intend that.

Try fixing these issues and your code might work better - as I say it's really hard to tell without sample data!

In any case iterating over the data character by character, row by row is incredibly inefficient, and will take forever unless your data set is small.

There's almost certainly a better way to do what you're trying to.

Comment: I added sample data

Comment: the problem is that the field NOTE_DESC is free test So I have to go through and find what I am looking for

Comment: What happens if you change your declaration and initialisation as I suggest?

Comment: the junk field changes to NULl but nothing else changes

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - didn't you already say that part of the problem is that JUNK is NULL? So nothing changes?
I suggest you set up a SQL fiddle with your code and some sample data so we can help further: http://sqlfiddle.com/